# How to collect and send file from S3 to ec2 SFTP folder using Lambda + python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, triggers

I want to write a python lambda function to send s3 bucket files to sftp folder on ec2 instance.
I am not able to create sftp server and how can I proceed with this problem statement.
First as new file get copied to s3 the lambda should trigger and copy those files to ec2 instance sftp folder

Comment: "I am not able to create sftp server" - what does it mean? What is your code? Why it does not work? What you have tried so far exactly?

Comment: Have you considered using Transfer for S3, which allows you to create a managed SFTP frontend for S3 without having to provision an EC2 instance?

Comment: Why do you want to use SFTP to send files to EC2? A better method would be to have the EC2 instance retrieve the file(s) from Amazon S3 directly. Please Edit your question to provide information about _what_ you are wanting to achieve (rather than _how_).